# Optimization of local variables in Objective C loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, optimization, loops, compiler-construction

I remember many years ago they were teaching us to create local variables outside of loops, e.g.:

```
SomeVariable* var;
for(int i; i<10; i++)
{
    var = [someArray objectAtIndex:i];
    (...)
}
```

I would assume that with modern compilers such optimization is done automatically, e.g. in Objective C the code below would be optimized to execute as fast as the code above:

```
for(int i; i<10; i++)
{
    SomeVariable* var = [someArray objectAtIndex:i];
    (...)
}
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for-in` loop is optimized to execute as fast.

Eg:

```
for( SomeVariable *var in someArray )
{
    //do something with var
}
```

Comment: Really? What about loop unrolling.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this and much stuff around (outlining of loop, branch prediction etc.) will be done automatically by your compiler. There is no need for premature optimization.

Just get in touch with best practices and "good design patterns" and let the compiler do it's work!

Nice article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization) and if you are really interested in learning more about it, I would recommend reading "Aho, Lam, Sethi, Ullman, Compilers Principles, Techniques, and Tools, Second Edition. Addison-Wesley, 2006."

Comment: Thanks for the links to Wikipedia and the book. I am aware of the optimization techniques, just wanted to confirm that the optimization takes place in OjbectiveC compiles as expected because I am looking after someone's else code where there are lots of statements like in my question.